# Android getting images from WCF Rest Service

Tags: android, wcf, image, http-get

I am pretty new to both Android and WCF.  I am making a user table with a very small image in the sql server db as varbinary.  In my service I have the following OperationContract:

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "users/{emailAddress}/Image", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    System.IO.Stream GetImage(string emailAddress);
```

Implementation:

```
      public System.IO.Stream GetImage(string emailAddress)
   {
       //parse personID, call DB
       string query = "Select profilePic from Flows_Users WHERE emailAddress= @emailAddress";
       SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection();

       DataSet ObjDataset = new DataSet();
       SqlDataAdapter objAdapater = new SqlDataAdapter();
       SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(query, objConnection);
       objCommand.Parameters.Add("emailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = emailAddress;
       objConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ToString();
       objConnection.Open();
       byte[] pic = (byte[])objCommand.ExecuteScalar();
       objConnection.Close();

       // if (pic == null)
       //     return null;

       OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

       // //if (image_not_found_in_DB)
       // //{
       // //    context.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
       // //    context.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.Location, url_of_a_default_image);
       // //    return null;
       // //}

       ////  everything is OK, so send image

       context.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "public");
       context.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
       // context.LastModified = date_image_was_stored_in_database;
       context.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
       return new System.IO.MemoryStream(pic);
   }
```

Is there any way to read this into an Android Image View?  I was unable to do it the base64 JSON way because the string kept terminating every time I tried to put it in a JSONArray.

Any help would be appreciated, I have been working on this since Saturday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a MemoryStream object. Return a Base64 encoded byte array of your image instead.

On the Android side then you can turn it back into an image and place it in your ImageView.